# Strip a sentence with [bold] tags

Tags: javascript, json, idml

I need to make a script which generates this code:

```
<CharacterStyleRange FillColor="">
    <Properties>
        <AppliedFont type="string">Agency FB</AppliedFont>
    </Properties>
    <Content>Hallo</Content>
</CharacterStyleRange>

<CharacterStyleRange FillColor="" FontStyle="Bold">
        <Properties>
            <AppliedFont type="string">Agency FB</AppliedFont>
        </Properties>
    <Content>ik</Content>
</CharacterStyleRange>

<CharacterStyleRange FillColor="">
        <Properties>
            <AppliedFont type="string">Agency FB</AppliedFont>
        </Properties>
    <Content>ben een zin</Content>
</CharacterStyleRange>

<CharacterStyleRange FillColor="" FontStyle="Bold">
        <Properties>
            <AppliedFont type="string">Agency FB</AppliedFont>
        </Properties>
    <Content>Met bold</Content>
</CharacterStyleRange>
```

From this:

```
Hallo [bold]ik[/bold] ben een zin [bold]met bold[/bold]
```

Basically what I want is to strip the sentence with the [bold] [/bold] tags, and make a new  (with all the other items as shown) for it.

I've tried a couple things but haven't been able to get it properly working, so now I am asking it here.

The language which it has to be transferred into is IDML(This language is used to build InDesign documents)

Comment: @ChrisDavis `var str   =  "Hallo [bold]ik[/bold] ben een zin [bold]met bold[/bold]";
var spited =  str.split("[bold]");

console.log(spited.toString().replace(",", "").split("[/bold]"));


if(str.indexOf("[bold]") != -1){
 console.log(str.indexOf("[bold]") + "contains [bold]");
}else{
 console.log(str.indexOf("[bold]") + "does not contain [bold]");
}`

Comment: Looks like you need a combination of  `str.split(" ")` and `regex` . Are you allowed to use regular expressions in this case?

Comment: @benjaminz What do you mean with being allowed to use it? Could you give me a example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Regular expression to extract all these text enclosed in `[bold]`.

```
var exp = "[bold]ik[/bold]";
var re = exp.match(/\[bold\](.*)\[\/bold\]/); //=> Array [ "[bold]ik[/bold]", "ik" ]
return re[1];
```

You will get `"ik"`.

Comment: Thanks although this is not wat i meant.
I want to strip the [bold] [/bold] tags, and generate this code from what's in between the [bold] [/bold] tags: `<CharacterStyleRange FillColor="" FontStyle="Bold">
        <Properties>
            <AppliedFont type="string">Agency FB</AppliedFont>
        </Properties>
    <Content>ik</Content>
</CharacterStyleRange>`
And for what is not in [bold] tags, i want this:`<CharacterStyleRange FillColor="">
    <Properties>
        <AppliedFont type="string">Agency FB</AppliedFont>
    </Properties>
    <Content>Hallo</Content>
</CharacterStyleRange>`

Comment: @Ivarr08 then after that you can add other parts of the string  "<CharacterStyleRange FillColor="" FontStyle="Bold">
        <Properties>
            <AppliedFont type="string">Agency FB</AppliedFont>
        </Properties>
    <Content>Met bold</Content>
</CharacterStyleRange>" with the data you extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this resource is helpful for you:
https://regex101.com/r/xU5jO9/2
There is my regex explained on the right side.

Try this in your console:

```
var myString = "Hallo [bold]ik[/bold] ben een zin [bold]met bold[/bold]";
var regex = new RegExp(/(\[bold\]?)(.*?)(\[\/bold\]?)/gi);
var replacePattern = "<CharacterStyleRange FillColor=\"\">     <Properties>         <AppliedFont type=\"string\">$2</AppliedFont>     </Properties>     <Content>Hallo</Content> </CharacterStyleRange>";

myString.replace(regex, replacePattern);
```

I haven't testet it but outside the console it should keep the line breaks. Otherwise open up your project in a text editor like sublime and do the same there. Better make a copy/ git commit first. In Sublime use `\2` instead of `$2`.

EDIT: I added the `?` non greedy operator, otherwise it will match form the first bold opening tag to the last closing tag.